# How to Change the Custom Color Lable text color using javafx css

Tags: javafx-8

How can I resolve visibility concerns when modifying the background color of a JavaFX ColorPicker, particularly with the "Custom Color" label becoming less noticeable on hover? Is it a label or a hyperlink, and can CSS be used to improve text color for better visibility?